# Implement Oauth2 together with own app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth-2.0

I have an application using Devise. And I want to use OAuth2 in my API for authentication.

- Is it possible to implement OAuth2 without using Doorkeeper, OmniAuth etc?
- How could I implement OAuth2 in my app because it must provide 'client_id', 'client_secret', :site?

Comment: You need to register your application with the OAuth2 provider (i.e. Facebook, google or whomever) and the rest is simple GET and POST HTTP requests. The libraries are wrappers around the OAuth2 authentication flow and the provider's API. You can look here for an [example implementation used by Plezi](https://github.com/boazsegev/plezi/blob/7a4e749908e2f22a0f27d4b4bf46360660d8a0ba/lib/plezi/oauth/auth_controller.rb)

Comment: You are saying that I need to get into the server such (Facebook, Google ect)? What if I want to use my own server (my app since has users also)? Is it possible?

Comment: Do you want to be an OAuth2 provider? or is your intention to allow your users to login using their Facebook (or other OAuth2) account?

Comment: I want other app to connect with my app.

Comment: So it's the same, but in reverse. You need to supply app_ids and secrets to your registered developers (to identify the application receiving the privileges from your end-user) and answer POST and GET requests according to the OAuth2 specifications. Again, you can do it without using existing gems... but they will make it easier (since it can be a lot of work to implement the service).

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to implement OAuth2 without using Doorkeeper, OmniAuth etc?

Yes, of course. But you would have to do all the work yourself based on the oAuth 2.0 standard. You can read the specification on what you have to do [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749).

> How could I implement OAuth2 in my app because it must provide 'client_id', 'client_secret', :site?

Read the oAuth 2.0 specs and implement them using standard Rails code. But, it would be much easier to just use existing gems. Also, it is better to use existing well maintained and popular gems, because oAuth2 standard has couple of nuances like setting random "state" while getting a request token. If not considered, that might lead to MiM attacks.